# Why do strange boxes appear on my Linux Mint MATE?

Tags: linux-mint, mate-desktop

[image]

I'm using Linux Mint MATE with Paper theme

Comment: Seems like the boxes come from eclipse, not from the desktop manager.

Comment: @gerhardd. The boxes appearing in some other applications apart from Eclipse.